# docker-compose not mounting folder for test results

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

After running unittests as part of building a docker-compose file, a file created in the container is not showing up on my local filesystem.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
# IDM.Test/Dockerfile
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0
WORKDIR /src

# Variables
ENV RESTORE_POLICY --no-restore
ENV IGNORE_WARNINGS -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503

# Restore
COPY IDM.sln ./

# Copying and restoring other projects...

COPY IDM.Test/IDM.Test.csproj IDM.Test/
RUN dotnet restore IDM.Test/IDM.Test.csproj $IGNORE_WARNINGS

# Copy
COPY . .

# Test
RUN dotnet test IDM.Test/IDM.Test.csproj -l "trx;LogFileName=test-results.xml"
RUN ls -alR
```

When running `RUN ls -alR` I can see that the file `/src/IDM.Test/TestResults/test-results.xml` is produced within the container. So far so good.

I'm using `docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml build` to start building. 
The docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  idm.webapi:
    image: idmwebapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: IDM.Test/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./IDM.Test/TestResults:/IDM.Test/TestResults/
```

I have created the folder `IDM.Test/TestResults` locally, but nothing appears after successfully running the docker-compose build command.

Any clues?

Comment: could you change `./IDM.Test/TestResults:/IDM.Test/TestResults/` to `./IDM.Test/TestResults:/IDM.Test/TestResults` (removing the last slash)

Comment: tried, didn't work

Comment: are you sure that the directory `/IDM.Test/TestResults` is in the root of the container?

Comment: in the dockerfile the `/src` is set as workdir and upon successful build i get this output: `Total tests: 183. Passed: 183. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Successful.
Test execution time: 23.1050 Seconds
Results File: /src/IDM.Test/TestResults/test-results.xml
Removing intermediate container d84ea055f2b6
 ---> 10e517b0dfcb
Successfully built 10e517b0dfcb
Successfully tagged idmwebapi:latest
`

Showing the file in path: ` /src/IDM.Test/TestResults/test-results.xml`

Comment: in this case you have to mount the volume `./IDM.Test/TestResults:/src/IDM.Test/TestResults`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with this explanation we can solve it. Let me say some obvious things to avoid confusion, step by step. Container creation has two steps:

1. docker build / docker-compose build -> Creates image
2. docker run / docker compose up / docker-compose run -> Creates container

Volumes are created in SECOND STEP (**container creation**), while your command `dotnet test IDM.Test/IDM.Test.csproj -l "trx;LogFileName=test-results.xml"` is being executed in first one (**image creation**).

> If you creates a folder inside container in the same path where you've
>   mounted volume, data in this new folder will only be available locally
>   inside container.

Definitively, my recommendation can be resumed in the following points:

- Check that destination folder of mounted volume is not created in building phase, so, is not defined any `RUN mkdir /IDM.Test/TestResults/` in your Dockerfile.
- Another little recommendation is not mandatory but I like to define volumes with absolute path in docker-compose file.
- Don't execute commands in Dockerfile which produce data you want outside, unless you specify this command as an ENTRYPOINT or CMD, not RUN.
- In Dockerfile, ENTRYPOINT or CMD (or command: in docker-compose) specify commands executed after buildind, when container starts.

Try with this Dockerfile:

```
# IDM.Test/Dockerfile
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0
WORKDIR /src

# Variables
ENV RESTORE_POLICY --no-restore
ENV IGNORE_WARNINGS -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503

# Restore
COPY IDM.sln ./

# Copying and restoring other projects...

COPY IDM.Test/IDM.Test.csproj IDM.Test/
RUN dotnet restore IDM.Test/IDM.Test.csproj $IGNORE_WARNINGS

# Copy
COPY . .

# Test
CMD dotnet test IDM.Test/IDM.Test.csproj -l "trx;LogFileName=test-results.xml"
```

Or this docker-compose:
version: '3'

```
services:
  idm.webapi:
    image: idmwebapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: IDM.Test/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./IDM.Test/TestResults:/IDM.Test/TestResults/
    command: >
      dotnet test IDM.Test/IDM.Test.csproj -l "trx;LogFileName=test-results.xml"
```

After container creation, you can check with `ls` your generated files.

Comment: Thanks, using `docker-compose up` instead of `docker-compose build` did the trick.